# .toggle() hides element for split second then brings it back

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I've wrote a function on the click of a html button that has a 'run at server' asp tag on the front end as below:

```
<button id="hidePast" runat="server" visible="True"><i class='fa fa-eye-slash'></i> Hide/Show Past Bookings</button>
```

And I want this to toggle a row on and off based on an If statment. From debugging the code it takes the correct path to hit the .toggle(), but when it does you can see the screen flicker as expected during a postback and you can see the row disappear and set re-added.

So far I've tried:

- e.preventDefault()
- e.stopImmediatePropagation()
- Using a hidden field to update a session to remember the state of the toggle

None of which have worked so far. The JS code is:

```
$(document).on('click','#ctl00_content_hidePast',function (e) {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    var dt = new Date($.now() - 30 * 60000);
    var time = dt.getHours() + ":" + dt.getMinutes() + ":" + dt.getSeconds();
    var state = $("#ctl00_content_hdnPastBookingToggle").val();
    $("td.bgtime").each(function() {
         var bookingTime = ($(this).text().split(':'));
         var d = new Date();
         d.setHours(+bookingTime[0]);
         d.setMinutes(bookingTime[1]);

         if ($(d) > time) {
             var timeRow = $(this).parent();
             $(timeRow).toggle();
         };
    });
    if (state === "0") {
       $("#ctl00_content_hdnPastBookingToggle").val("1");
    } 
    else if (state === "1") {
       $("#ctl00_content_hdnPastBookingToggle").val("0");
    };
    return false;
 });
});
```

Comment: my guess wtihout seeing it is you have 2 children so the parent toggle gets called twice.

Comment: Check it with .hide() to and it's the same result plus at the moment there's only one row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following worked in the end.

Changing the button to:

```
<button id="hidePast" runat="server" onclick="return false;" causesvalidation="false" visible="True"><i class='fa fa-eye-slash'></i> Hide/Show Past Bookings</button>
```

And the JQuery to:

```
$(function togglePast () {
            $(document)
                .on('click',
                    '#ctl00_content_hidePast',
                    function (e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        var dt = new Date($.now() - 30 * 60000);
                        var time = dt.getTime();
                        var state = $("#<%= hdnPastBookingToggle.ClientID %>").val();
                        $("td.bgtime")
                            .each(function() {
                                var bookingTime = ($(this).text().split(':'));
                                var d = new Date();
                                d.setHours(parseInt(bookingTime[0]));
                                d.setMinutes(parseInt(bookingTime[1]));
                                var rowTime = d.getTime();

                                console.log("Now: " + time + " Time from row: " + rowTime);

                                if (rowTime < time) {
                                    var timeRow = $(this).parent();
                                    $(timeRow).toggle("slow");
                                };
                            });
                        if (state === "0") {
                            $("#<%= hdnPastBookingToggle.ClientID %>").val("1");
                        } else if (state === "1") {
                            $("#<%= hdnPastBookingToggle.ClientID %>").val("0");
                        };
                        return false;
                    });
        });
```

The biggest changes I made were to the button and that was to add both  `onclick="return false;" causesvalidation="false"` as the above did not work without one or the other.